# Table/View does not exist on Derby + Netbeans Connect

Tags: sql, netbeans, derby

I am trying to make this connection with Derby in Netbeans for products registration. Connection with Database seems okay, but when I try to insert an object in a statement it returns Table/View does not exist error. Already tried to read other cases of the same error in the forum, but looks that my case is different. I tried to verify case sensitive names it's okay, tried to execute an sql command directly from Netbeans, the table appears with its columns. (I'm not using the app in the dist folder, I'm executing from Netbeans)

My insert:
[image: Imagem 1]
Here, in the connection no problem, it finds the BD:
[image: Imagem2]
Executing a command from Netbeans table is okay:
[image: Imagem3]
Error in GUI:
[image: Imagem4]

Answer (score 0):

You might be using two different `Mercado` databases. If you search your hard disk for a folder by the name 'Mercado', I believe you may find two of them:

1. When you connect with the Netbeans IDE, you are accessing the Derby Network Server, which has a "home" directory somewhere on your hard disk, and it is storing the database using the relative pathname `Mercado`.
2. When you run your standalone program, you are using the Embedded Driver, not the Client/Server Driver, so your standalone program is accessing the database using the relative pathname `Mercado`

Unless you have very carefully ensured that your standalone test program is running with its current working directory pointed at the same location that is being used by the Derby Network Server as its database home directory, then you have probably created two different `Mercado` databases and that is why your data is found in one of them and not the other.